# How to create a Eloquent model instance from a raw Object?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to make a raw database query using Laravel:

```
$results = DB::select("SELECT * FROM members 
    INNER JOIN (several other tables) 
    WHERE (horribly complicated thing) 
    LIMIT 1");
```

I get back a plain PHP StdClass Object with fields for the properties on the members table. I'd like to convert that to a Member (an Eloquent model instance), which looks like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model {
}
```

I'm not sure how to do it since a Member doesn't have any fields set on it, and I'm worried I will not initialize it properly. What is the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Did you try to just do a Member model and and fetch data from there?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean translating the where clauses and the inner joins into ORM code, no, I don't want to do that.

Comment: What exactly do you want to retrieve from the database?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can try to hydrate your results to Model objects:

```
$results = DB::select("SELECT * FROM members 
                       INNER JOIN (several other tables) 
                       WHERE (horribly complicated thing) 
                       LIMIT 1");

$models = Member::hydrate( $results->toArray() );
```

Or you can even let Laravel auto-hydrate them for you from the raw query:

```
$models = Member::hydrateRaw( "SELECT * FROM members...");
```

**EDIT**

From Laravel 5.4 *hydrateRaw* is no more available. We can use *fromQuery* instead:

```
$models = Member::fromQuery( "SELECT * FROM members...");
```

Comment: This is good, but you'll get a collection of models. The `LIMIT 1` makes no sense here.

Comment: When I do this, I can't select relationships anymore... How come?

Comment: "The LIMIT 1 makes no sense here." - it does if you want a collection of 1, and not a singular

Answer (score -3):

You can simply init a new model:

```
$member = new App\Member;
```

Then you can assign the columns:

```
$member->column = '';
```

Or if all columns are mass assignable:

```
$member->fill((array)$results);
```

Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Totally off topic answer, `fill()` is used to updated the given fillable columns.

Answer (score -7):

You should definetly use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) to perform that.

You might declare the relations between the models, and use the where conditions.

like:

```
Member::where(......)->get();
```

This will return an eloquent instance, and you can do whatever you need.

Comment: I dont get it why it has a downvote. It's almost the same answer as the one above, but mine is enterily based on eloquent, these are two possible answers for the same question.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. OP needs to use a complex SQL query which returns **raw** data. The question is about creating a new model instance from that raw data.

Comment: I totally downvote answers that are not answers, but suggestion of another (hopefully better) way to do a thing. Often, as in this case, these answers don't get the point and the better way is not a feasable way, or doesn't answer the OP question. So why bother? just to show off? Stick to the point, if you don't know the answer, refrain from answer.

Comment: This is out of requirements. We need to convert an array into specific model